# Metro app how to create grouped GridView in the C# code behind

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

In my metro app I need to show groups of VariableSizeWrapGrid on a GridView. Doing this is straight forward in XAML(by creating ItemsPanelTemplate and GroupStyle). But is there a way to do the same in C# code behind.

Comment: I tried setting GroupStyle property to the GridView in the C# code but is read only. But in XAML we can set GroupStyles.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.groupstyle.aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace GroupingSample
{
    public partial class Window1 : System.Windows.Window
    {

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        CollectionView myView;
        private void AddGrouping(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            myView = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myItemsControl.ItemsSource);
            if (myView.CanGroup == true)
            {
                PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription
                    = new PropertyGroupDescription("@Type");
                myView.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
            }
            else 
                return;
        }

        private void RemoveGrouping(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            myView = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myItemsControl.ItemsSource);
            myView.GroupDescriptions.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

The key here is that you get the default view off of the `ItemsSource` and set the grouping on that.  This line:

```
myView = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myItemsControl.ItemsSource);
```